My Django project settings seem to form an error
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/Billing/
Using the URLconf defined in eCommerce.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
The current path, Billing/, didn’t match any of these.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

This is shown when I tried to create an app using django
Here is the code for the program
main.urls
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from BillingST.eCommerce.Billing import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("Billing/", include('Billing.urls')),
    path('', views.access, name='access')
]

billing.urls
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('Billing/', include('Billing.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

I was trying to run the code for billing page, but it says to navigate to admin

So what is the name of the project, and what is the app? Please share a filetree with the relevant files. For Unix-based operating systems, the tree command can often be used. Then [edit] the question, and include the result in a code fragment.

The error could be because you used include('Billing.urls'), when the actual name is billing.urls with a lowercase b.  Or it could be because billing.urls tries to include itself.  Or it could be because you edited main/urls.py but forgot to save it.

Please [edit] the question with a more descriptive title. Currently the title does not make it very clear what the issue is about.

Your billing.urls essentially make it impossible to visit a view, since it keeps recursively including.
Indeed, first there is the main.urls, which looks like:
path('Billing/', include('Billing.urls'))
so that means it will only go to Billing.urls if the path starts with Billing/, which it does.
But then we see:
path('Billing/', include('Billing.urls'))
in the billing.urls, so if there is a second Billing/ in the path, it will descend to the next level, but even if that is the case, it will keep looking for more Billing/s.
Rewrite the billing.urls to:
# billing/urls.py

from BillingST.eCommerce.Billing import views
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.access),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
and remove the view from the main.urls:
# main/urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

# from BillingST.eCommerce.Billing import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('Billing/', include('Billing.urls')),
    # path('', views.access, name='access')
]


Note: Python modules are normally written in snake_case, not PascalCase, so it
should be billing, not Billing.


The issue is how your URL patterns are structured and included.
main.urls - You include Billing.urls with the path "Billing/". This means Django will look for patterns in Billing.urls prefixed by "Billing/."
billing.urls - Inside Billing.urls, you're including Billing.urls again (recursive inclusion). This causes a loop and breaks the URLs. Billing.urls doesn't define any valid endpoint, so you get a 404.
Define the correct URL structure for Billing
main.urls -
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("Billing/", include('Billing.urls')),  # Include Billing app URLs
]

billing.urls -

Do not include Billing.urls within itself.

from django.urls import path
from . import views  # Import the views for the Billing app

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.billing_home),
    path("details/", views.billing_details),
]

